# Получение списка файлов из указаного каталога

Tags: java, файлы

Добрый день. Задача следующая. На вход подается определенный каталог. Нужно получить список всех файлов и сохранить его в список. В каталоге могут быть подкаталоги, в подкаталогах подкаталоги и т.д. Думаю, суть ясна.
На выходе должен получится обыкновенный список файлов (выводится полный путь к файлу) без вложенных каталогов.
Подскажите как можно решить эту задачу. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А что именно у вас не получилось?

Comment: Пока никак не могу придумать как это сделать рекурсивно

Comment: Вы же можете получить список файлов из директории. Дальше `for (File file : dir) if (file.isDir()) findRec(file); else LIST.add(file.getFullName());`

Answer (score 2):

```
List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(dir, null, true);
for (File file : files) {
            System.out.println("file: " + file.getCanonicalPath());
}


file: C:\projects\workspace\testing\dir\anotherdir\hamburger.jsp
file: C:\projects\workspace\testing\dir\anotherdir\test2.txt
file: C:\projects\workspace\testing\dir\test1.txt
```